# Overhead of tf.data.Dataset.from_generator vs plain python generator

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use tf.data as an input pipeline to my tensorflow model. Currently I have a python generator that can generate around 16000 samples/sec. If I use this generator with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator the performance drops to around 2500 samples/sec. Where does this overhead come from and is there away to reduce this overhead? Cause at the moment, I'm having trouble utilizing my GPU.

Here's a super simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

def gen():
    while True:
        x = np.zeros(shape=(1, 20000), dtype=np.float32)
        yield x, x


en_py = gen()
gen_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen, 
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 20000), dtype=tf.float32), 
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 20000), dtype=tf.float32)
    )
)

tfds.benchmark(gen_py, batch_size=1, num_iter=500_000)  # this create 350000 samples/sec
tfds.benchmark(gen_tf, batch_size=1, num_iter=500_000)  # this creates 5800 samples/sec
```

I know the example is extremely simple, but the output shapes roughly fit the output of the generator I use to get the data for my model.